# Unable to debug Go applications in IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, go, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I am unable to run Go tests, in IntelliJ Idea, using the Green "Play" button in the IDE.

The vast majority of my Go development is down outside of `$GOPATH`, but all my environment variables are set correctly so this has never been a problem.

I created a dummy project, in my Desktop directory, with the following structure...

```
.
├── main.go
├── main_test.go
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

func Add(a, b int) int {
    return a+b
}
```

`main_test.go`

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    res := Add(1, 2)

    if res != 3 {
        t.Errorf("Fail")
    }
}
```

I can run the test fine from the command line (`go test .`) and I can use VSCodes `run test` button in the IDE fine, but when I try the "Play" button in IntelliJ I get `./main_test.go:6:9: undefined: Add`.

As per [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003263520-Couple-of-problems-coming-from-VSCode) IntelliJ Support Question, I've made sure my Go Test template is set to "directory" but I can't seem to get it to work as it recreates a new config every time set to the file.

Any help appreciated...

**edit 1:** I have just moved over from VScode to IntelliJ, which is what I meant by my above statement of "so this has never been a problem". It has not worked in IntelliJ since I downloaded it a couple of days ago.

Comment: The package should have a `main()` function.

Comment: I was not able to find outflow of the project in IntelliJ so I tried to use goland. now I can see the whole flow and debug, compile my project.

Comment: @SimoEndre - yes, it should. But this is just a dummy project to show the issue of it not being able to find the "Add" function from the test file.

Comment: @VrushaliRaut - Goland is not an option, unfortunately. I have an Idea license, not a Goland one.

Comment: why don't you use goland? that is the intellij ide that was made for go, i am not sure if the go plugin for intellij is up to date

Comment: @Pizzalord because goland isn't included in the IntelliJ Ultimate license that I have. I checked with them and they said the Go plugin for IDEA is up-to-date with goland.

Comment: strange because when i use goland your code work, but with intellij your code does not, this makes me think it might be a bug in the go plugin

Comment: @Pizzalord that's strange - I downloaded the Goland trial to see if it works, but even with Goland I get the same issue. Did you have to change a setting somewhere to make it work with Goland?

Comment: @grpcMe i ran it from go/src/username/test/ which had both files

Comment: @Pizzalord ahh ok, yes that makes sense. It does work when I'm working in `$GOPATH`, but not when I'm outside it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be `$GOPATH` is problem.

Correct GOPATH Project.

```
$GOPATH/src/hello/main.go
$GOPATH/src/hello/main_test.go
```

But Incorrect GOPATH Project.

```
/hello/main.go
/hello/main_test.go
```

Comment: My project is not located in `$GOPATH`.

Comment: must be project folder in $GOPATH. document is https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH

Comment: My `$GOPATH` is set, but the project does not have to be in `$GOPATH`. If this was the issue, then VSCode wouldn't be working; nor would the command line....

Comment: it is the GOPATH problem. As the package has no import path, GoLand supposes that it knows nothing about this package and do not compile all files around the given function. As I said in the issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-7013) we don't want to encourage users to use non-recommended project layout.